# Are there security implications to using dynamically-assigned TCP port numbers?

Tags: security, sockets, dynamic

I'm getting pushback from operations for having a server process listen on a dynamically-assigned port number (i.e. it binds a socket to a port number of 0, triggering a dynamic assignment by the OS, which it retrieves using getsocketname()).  The argument was that is "creates all kinds of issues for firewalling, routing, ACL, and security purposes".  I haven't run across anything about this.

This is CentOS, our applications are in-house and restricted to a set of machines on a LAN that's heavily firewalled from the outer world.

Can someone knowledgeable weigh in on the subject?

**UPDATE 1**: FTP dynamically assigns a port number, too, although I don't know if it's from the same range of numbers that I've seen elsewhere (32768-61000?).  How do firewalls etc. deal with this?

Comment: What happens in a few months when the service needs to be accessed through the firewall? How will it know which port(s) to allow?

Comment: Good point; what do firewalls do about FTP, which uses (as I understand it) the same technique?

Comment: Hopefully somebody with a lot more firewall experience than myself will come in here and give a proper answer but with regards to FTP communication is initiated on a static port (21 by default) and then occurs over a defined range of ports. The firewall is configured to match the static port and the range.

Comment: FTP is a special and difficult case.  Its use of _ad hoc_ ports for inbound connections has made many firewalls create special rules.  It's not a good model to emulate.

Comment: @RossPatterson usually you use ftp in passive mode when there's firewall to stop it from using random port number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Network administrators like to know *exactly* what ports your software will listen on, so that they can open *only* the required ports on the firewall defending their network from intrusion attacks. Protecting a network is all about knowing where an attack could come from. If your network, via its firewall, will never expect traffic on port 699, then if you ignore, discard or actively refuse all traffic requesting or transmitting on that port, an attacker can't get in to do his dirty deeds dirt cheap.

Your dynamic port scheme leaves the selection of the port up to the OS. If the OS can choose any non-reserved port for your service, then your network admin must keep all of those ports open between any two network addresses that may be using your software to communicate.

A "trusted" network environment is a misnomer. Most things you "trust" in IT security are things that are simply infeasible to not trust, or for which the reasons for your trust extend beyond the boundaries of the digital world. You may, for instance, have been given a public key certificate "offline" (via thumb drive, etc) and told it belongs to a particular website. By installing said certificate, you tell your computer that you trust the assertions made by the person who gave it to you. The computer then trusts your own judgement, but verifies that the certificate presented by the website matches exactly the cert it was told to trust.

To the case in point; your heavily-firewalled LAN is "trusted" only because using TLS (based partially on the above certificates) for all traffic inside the LAN, based on a PKI that touches every client machine, and administering firewalls between subnets and VLANs inside this environment, is more work than the network admin is willing to take responsibility for. He instead directs his efforts towards building a solid outer wall and gatekeeper system, ensuring that anything attempting to cross the boundary from the outside in (*or* the inside out) is doing so with at least apparently valid purpose.

Now, in fact, your network admin may *want* to put firewalls up at key gateways between LAN subnets and across leased lines or VPNs. By having this program use any port it chooses, you force the network admin *not* to add this "defense in depth" as long as your program works this way. He's not going to like that, and he's going to push back, hard, on any attempt to tell him he can't do his job the way he sees fit.

---

As far as the argument that dynamic ports are used all the time to connect, that's true - *for the client machine*. The port your server computer *listens* on must be static. FTP was mentioned, so we'll use that. FTP uses two ports, usually 20 and 21, for data transfer and command/control respectively. These ports are the ports the server computer will keep open and listen on, and which a firewall on the server side must allow all incoming requests to pass through.

FTP has two connection modes; "Active" and "Passive", and the client machine chooses which. In "active mode", the client will itself begin listening on a second dynamic port, and as part of the negotiation on port 21, will tell the FTP server which other port to SYN. When the client computer is not behind a firewall or other NAT layer, this is better for the server, as the server can now use a dynamic outbound port to "push" messages to the client instead of waiting for the client to send a request to which it can respond, and the server can also distinguish traffic on this port as being between itself and only one client. However, because the client can't tell a firewall protecting the client's network that it's expecting a valid incoming connection on the dynamic port it chose, this scheme is incompatible with a client behind a firewall or other NAT layer, because the firewall will simply deny the incoming request from the server as being unexpected "inbound" traffic.

Instead, for clients that know or presume they are being firewalled/NATed, the client can request "passive" connection negotiation. When the server receives a "passive" request on port 21, it begins listening on a second one of its ports (port 20 is reserved for this purpose, for situations involving a firewall in front of the server as well) and sends this port identifier to the client, who can then make a second "outgoing" connection to the server on which the client's firewall will then expect traffic. As virtually all clients are at least NATed in current times (home networks are ubiquitous), many FTP client programs don't even bother trying an active connection, and FTP servers are built to take all the traffic they'll get on just the two static ports.

In your model, from what you've said, you're basically trying to use an "active" connection scheme, where your software begins listening on a dynamic port and ostensibly tells the remote computer this port to facilitate a return connection. This is, as described, incompatible with a firewall, and so as long as your software behaves this way and cannot behave in any other way, no firewall can exist between two computers using your software. This may be contrary to your network admin's plans for his network.

Comment: Some firewalls *do* support "active" FTP connections. They do this by inspecting the FTP negotiation to see which additional port to open up, but that requires additional effort and knowledge of the FTP protocol in the firewall.

Comment: All true. I think the answer is long enough, though, and even if firewalls can support active FTP, the OP is unlikely to make them play nice with his own scheme.

Answer (score -1):

You should use ssh tunnels instead of dynamically assigning ports. Usually network administrators are cool with SSH ports. Also you can use SCP for secure file transfer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255091)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).